# Paypal cc validation from the site using cURL or Paypal API's?

Tags: paypal, payment

I have a cc form in the site. After the customer fills the form and in the background(using curl or fsock etc.. or through API calls) the cc details can be validated with Paypal? any API's exists? This is something like authorize.net payment integration

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want [Paypal's Instant Payment Notification](https://www.paypal.com/ipn) .